# Create Query with auto complete on server side

Tags: java, hibernate, solr, lucene, hibernate-search

I have java swing application with text field. 
I need to create JIRA like text search with auto-complete (See image below) for example:

```
firstName = John AND lastName = Smith AND age > 35
```

I need to send this query text to Server. On the server side I need to transfer this text to Hibernate Criteria perform Search and return list to the client side.
`firstName, lastName and age` are `User.class` properties which has appropriate getters and setters.

Is there any java framework that can help me to transform such string to Hibernate criteria? Solr, Lucene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use the [Hibernate Search Framework](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html)
You can add this on top of your Hibernate Configuration and retrieve the results from a lucene index which is build from the data available in your database.